# Where is the database stored when using SQLAlchemy and Flask?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

The document gives the following example URI `SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'sqlite:////tmp/test.db'` to put in the `config.py` file.

I was wondering what does that mean (since I do not have a `sqlite` directory in my project and `////` seems very strange to me) and where does the test.db file is stored?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general format of a SQLAlchemy connection URI is

```
dialect://user:password@server:port/database
```

With SQLite you don't have user, password, server, or port so the general form becomes

```
sqlite:///database
```

If the absolute path to your SQLite database file is `/tmp/test.db` then the URI is

```
sqlite:////tmp/test.db
```